# onStateChange on NavigationContainer with undefined param

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation

I'm using a `NavigationContainer` inside a `NavigationContainer` with React Navigation 5. Before that, I was testing with a `NavigationContainer` from navigation 5 inside a `createAppContainer` in navigation 4 and it worked normally.

**The problem is**: when my second NavigationContainer calls the `onStateChange` function, the received parameter is undefined. In addition, when using a ref, the `getRootState` method also returns undefined. I can use the ref to navigate between screens and also call the goBack function normally.

An example code:

```
const navigationRef = React.useRef();
```

The second navigation:

```
<NavigationContainer
  independent={true}
  ref={navigationRef}
  onStateChange={navigationChanged}
>
  <BusinessNavigation />
</NavigationContainer>;
```

Works fine:

```
navigationRef.current.resetRoot({
  routes,
  index: 0
});
```

```
navigationRef.current.goBack();
```

problems:

```
navigationRef.current.getRootState(); //returns always undefined
```

```
const navigationChanged = (params: any) => {
  console.log(params); //is undefined
};
```

Comment: I am experiencing the same thing. Did you manage to fix it?

Comment: I am now using the listener and it is working fine to solve my problem. Code sample:

navigationRef.current.addListener('state', e => {
    const state = e.data.state; //works
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am now using the listener and it is working fine to solve my problem. Code sample:

```
navigationRef.current.addListener('state', e => {
    const state = e.data.state; //works
});
```